# AS3 AIR : After stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,... stage width and height changes?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm noob and trying some ActionScript3 code and now I'm stuck with this problem.

**I can't figure out why stage height changes after *addEventListener*.**

Can someone help please?

I don't know is this code enough to find what's wrong with it. But here's the code:

```
...
[SWF(frameRate="60",width="768",height="1280",backgroundColor="#1c1c1c")]
...

    private function loop():void {
        trace("waiting for mouse");
        trace("stage height before mouse click: ",stage.stageHeight); 
        //here stage height is 1024

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouse);
    }

    private function mouse(event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("stage height after mouse click: ",stage.stageHeight);
        //here, after addEventListener stage height is 800

        var mouseX:Number = event.stageX;
        var mouseY:Number = event.stageY;
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loop);

        trace("click: ", mouseX, ",", mouseY);
        draw(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    private function draw(mouseX:int,mouseY:int):void {
    ...
    addChild(textField);
    loop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might not be caused by the event listener.  I would ask you what happens when you take that out and use a timer, but that would use an event listener of its own.

Comment: I don't understand why to put timer. I traced it before and after addEventListener and it changes value exactly after mouse click.
Can you elaborate how timer can help?

Comment: Well, the idea would have been to see if it just changes on its own after a few seconds, but since that requires its own event listener, it might not be a good test.

Comment: because the event listener happens in the new frame. And air app sets height and width in first frame or two, read the response below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably an issue of air app. If you are using air there are several frames on the start where air sets up the correct screen size.

To handle that first set up this.

```
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

This will dispatch an resize event once the stage height changes.

So, before you do anything in your app you add listeners in this order.

```
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.Resize, onResize);
    }

    private function onResize(event:Event):void {
        _resizeCounter ++;
        trace("stage.stageWidth is "+ stage.stageWidth);
        trace("stage.stageHeight is "+ stage.stageHeight);

        if (resizeCounter == ${dependsOnThePlatform}) {
             initializeTheApp();
        }
    }
```

Depending on the platform, you may need to listen for resize once or twice. Experiment with the `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.StageHeight` after the resize event

P.S. This all goes into the main App, and when you have everything set up you initialize Starling

Comment: yes it is AIR. 
ok, ok. I hear of this once before. I'll try and get back.

Comment: You should definitely be using onAddedToStage whether or not is solves your issue.

Comment: this answer doesn't solve my problem. I'm still checking possible answers.

Comment: di you try to debug to resize listener, and every time resize happens trace stage.stageWidth and height

Comment: yes I tried. no it doesn't trace it because it shoots out error 1136 and ties to convince me that my constructor has an argument which it doesn't.

Comment: I also tried viewport rect scheme but that also was't working

Comment: by the way what is the import for ResizeEvent?